# XSLT specific tags ordering by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML spreadsheet as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pd:ProcessDesc xmlns:pd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
...
<pd:activity name="send msg">
    <pd:type>com.myProj.ref</pd:type>
</pd:activity>
...
<pd:activity name="get msgs">
    <pd:type>om.myProj.ref</pd:type>
</pd:activity>
...
</pd:ProcessDesc>
```

What I need to sort only `activity` tags in it by its attribute `name=*` ascending, not touching any others.
I tried to do such a thing on many levels, however, each time either transformation was not working at all or all of the nodes under ProcessDesc were sorted.

Can anyone help me to find a way to sort these?

P.S. I think, that in all of my XSLT's the matching verb was not constructed correctly or at least I'm trying to match it in the wrong way.

Comment: So there can be other child elements of `pd:ProcessDesc` you have not shown? It might help to show a few and also indicate the result you want them from sorting. Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: The meaning of "not touching any others" is not clear. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854208/3016153. If not, post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, including the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think in XSLT 3 it could be done as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes">
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:pos" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$element">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="sorted-activities" select="sort(activity, (), function($f) { $f/@name})"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="* ! (if (. instance of element(activity)) then let $pos := mf:pos(.) return $sorted-activities[$pos] else .)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using `xsl:perform-sort` and `for .. return` it should be easy to downgrade that approach to XSLT 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:pos" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$element">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ProcessDesc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="sorted-activities" as="element(activity)*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="activity">
          <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="for $child-el in *
                return (
                   if ($child-el instance of element(activity)) 
                   then $sorted-activities[mf:pos($child-el)] 
                   else $child-el)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/eixk6Sx

Comment: Thanks @Martin, any online tool is parsing the XSLT as it should be, however, during build in maven I got:

"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:1.0.2:transform (default-cli) on project myProject: Failed to parse stylesheet javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource@39b21b3b: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected."

I used switches -e and -X, however, I could not resolve any error description. Do you have any idea why such an error could emerge, or at least how I can check the full error message?
I used Saxon 2.0

Comment: My bad. The error is visible in the console:
XTSE0010: Attribute @expand-text is not allowed on element <xsl:stylesheet>

The error is not occurring when I delete " expand-text="yes" ", however, then the transformation does not work

Comment: @CharlieMcPerson, sorry about the use of `expand-text`, but that was just boilerplate of the template for XSLT 3, so I think you can just remove that attribute. The XSLT 2 version of the code without the attribute works fine for me at http://xsltransform.net/eixk6Sx/1,  not sure why removing the attribute should make the other code fail. Make sure you have the right `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`, I used the one from your sample but as that is the namespace for XSLT itself and the XML doesn't look like XSLT I was not sure whether that is a mistake